# MomentJS time in spanish

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using the next code to convert a date received from a MySQL database format `1993-10-23 00:00:00` and display it in spanish:

```
alert(moment('1993-10-23 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'es'));
```

23 oct is saturday. I would expect to get `sábado` but I get the next:

```
Sat Oct 23 1993 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Also tried adding: `moment.locale('es-ES');` , `moment.locale('en-ES');` and `moment.locale('es');`
but neither works.

What's the correct way of converting dates from a language to another?

Comment: You're using the syntax for parsing a string, not outputting it. You want [*moment().format()*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Be careful with ISO 8601 like formats without a timezone, they are treated differently by ES5 (UTC) and ES6 (local).

Comment: @RobG thanks, check the answer, is there anything to add for the ISO format ?

Comment: ISO 8601 says that dates with a missing timezone should be treated as local, whereas ES5 says to treat them as UTC. ES6 changes to be consistent with ISO. To be sure, you should use '1993-10-23T00:00:00Z' if you want it treated as UTC. Add the required timezone if you want something else and parse it with Moment.js (or write your own 2 or 3 line function). The Javascript parse will only parse ISO 8601 UTC.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to work, thanks @RobG

```
var localLocale = moment('1993-10-23 00:00:00');
moment.locale('es');
localLocale.locale(false);
alert(localLocale.format('LLLL'));
```

Answer (score 3):

The following method worked for me

```js
moment(agreement.dateStart).locale('es').format('LLLL')
```