# Moment.JS accent mark in month, spanish?

Tags: javascript, c#, momentjs

I'm using moments js to convert from c# JSONified datetime `/Date(1501287730903)/` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35771712/5671022)

```
$scope.var = moment($scope.var).toDate();
```

My objective is to turn the variable that holds `/Date(1501287730903)/` not just into JS date, but a string like `05 Jan 2017`

```
$scope.var = moment($scope.var).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

works fine, but I am wanting the actual letters of month.  When I proceed to

```
$scope.var = moment($scope.var).format('DD/MMM/YYYY');
```

however, I get `28-júl-2017` and MMMM renders `29-júlí-2017`

I'm not sure but it looks like it's going for Spanish months..?  How can I specify English?

Comment: According to Google Translate that's Icelandic (`is-is` locale), in case you have to look for it in your code.

Comment: You will get `júl` as `MMM` month name using moment 2.18.1 for [Hungarian (hu)](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.18.1/locale/hu.js#L49), [Icelandic (is)](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.18.1/locale/is.js#L82) and [Slovak (sk)](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.18.1/locale/sk.js#L15)

Answer (score 5):

What is the locale that you have loaded into moment?
I am guessing that before this code you loaded the Spanish locale like this:

```
moment.locale('es-es');
```

Try to load the English locale before parsing the date like this:

```
moment.locale('en');
```

Comment: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30842477/5671022) I tried moment.locale('en').  Avi K, I think you're right.  I have no recollection of moving to spanish, but I'll check my code...